# JQuery: Drag and Drop inside a container

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

As i am new to JQuery and JavaScript, i was struggling to create a drag and drop function.

Here i need to drag and drop the icons from one container to another. 
Once an icon is dropped into right container the icon in left container must be grey scaled and once if icon is drag and dropped from right to left container it should come to normal color from grey scale. 
I just need to write a onclick function for right container icon that should not be working on left container.

Is there any way to do this. I tried lot of plugins but i failed.

Note: It should not be in HTML5.

[image]

Code:

***HTML***

```
<div id="columns">          
        <ul id="column2" class="column"> 
           <li id="image1"><img class="widget-head" src="img/addfuel@2x.png" id="1"/></li> 
           <li id="image2"><img class="widget-head" src="img/boatclean@2x.png" id="2"/></li> 
           <li id="image3"><img class="widget-head" src="img/diveservice@2x.png" id="3"/></li> 
           <li id="image4"><img class="widget-head" src="img/fooddrain@2x.png" id="4"/></li> 
        </ul> 

        <ul id="column3" class="column"></ul> 

    </div>
```

***JS***

```
var iNettuts = {

    jQuery : $,

    settings : {
        columns : '.column',
        widgetSelector: '.widget',
        handleSelector: '.widget-head',
        contentSelector: '.widget-content',
        widgetDefault : {
            movable: true,
            removable: true,
            collapsible: true,
            editable: true,
            colorClasses : ['color-yellow', 'color-red', 'color-blue', 'color-white', 'color-orange', 'color-green']
        },
        widgetIndividual : {
            intro : {
                movable: false,
                removable: false,
                collapsible: false,
                editable: false
            }
        }
    },

    init : function () {
        this.attachStylesheet('inettuts.js.css');
        this.addWidgetControls();
        this.makeSortable();
    },

    getWidgetSettings : function (id) {
        var $ = this.jQuery,
            settings = this.settings;
        return (id&&settings.widgetIndividual[id]) ? $.extend({},settings.widgetDefault,settings.widgetIndividual[id]) : settings.widgetDefault;
    },

    addWidgetControls : function () {
        var iNettuts = this,
            $ = this.jQuery,
            settings = this.settings;

        $(settings.widgetSelector, $(settings.columns)).each(function () {
            var thisWidgetSettings = iNettuts.getWidgetSettings(this.id);
            if (thisWidgetSettings.removable) {
                $('<a href="#" class="remove">CLOSE</a>').mousedown(function (e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();    
                }).click(function () {
                    if(confirm('This widget will be removed, ok?')) {
                        $(this).parents(settings.widgetSelector).animate({
                            opacity: 0    
                        },function () {
                            $(this).wrap('<div/>').parent().slideUp(function () {
                                $(this).remove();
                            });
                        });
                    }
                    return false;
                }).appendTo($(settings.handleSelector, this));
            }

            if (thisWidgetSettings.editable) {
                $('<a href="#" class="edit">EDIT</a>').mousedown(function (e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();    
                }).toggle(function () {
                    $(this).css({backgroundPosition: '-66px 0', width: '55px'})
                        .parents(settings.widgetSelector)
                            .find('.edit-box').show().find('input').focus();
                    return false;
                },function () {
                    $(this).css({backgroundPosition: '', width: ''})
                        .parents(settings.widgetSelector)
                            .find('.edit-box').hide();
                    return false;
                }).appendTo($(settings.handleSelector,this));
                $('<div class="edit-box" style="display:none;"/>')
                    .append('<ul><li class="item"><label>Change the title?</label><input value="' + $('h3',this).text() + '"/></li>')
                    .append((function(){
                        var colorList = '<li class="item"><label>Available colors:</label><ul class="colors">';
                        $(thisWidgetSettings.colorClasses).each(function () {
                            colorList += '<li class="' + this + '"/>';
                        });
                        return colorList + '</ul>';
                    })())
                    .append('</ul>')
                    .insertAfter($(settings.handleSelector,this));
            }

            if (thisWidgetSettings.collapsible) {
                $('<a href="#" class="collapse">COLLAPSE</a>').mousedown(function (e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();    
                }).toggle(function () {
                    $(this).css({backgroundPosition: '-38px 0'})
                        .parents(settings.widgetSelector)
                            .find(settings.contentSelector).hide();
                    return false;
                },function () {
                    $(this).css({backgroundPosition: ''})
                        .parents(settings.widgetSelector)
                            .find(settings.contentSelector).show();
                    return false;
                }).prependTo($(settings.handleSelector,this));
            }
        });

        $('.edit-box').each(function () {
            $('input',this).keyup(function () {
                $(this).parents(settings.widgetSelector).find('h3').text( $(this).val().length>20 ? $(this).val().substr(0,20)+'...' : $(this).val() );
            });
            $('ul.colors li',this).click(function () {

                var colorStylePattern = /\bcolor-[\w]{1,}\b/,
                    thisWidgetColorClass = $(this).parents(settings.widgetSelector).attr('class').match(colorStylePattern)
                if (thisWidgetColorClass) {
                    $(this).parents(settings.widgetSelector)
                        .removeClass(thisWidgetColorClass[0])
                        .addClass($(this).attr('class').match(colorStylePattern)[0]);
                }
                return false;

            });
        });

    },

    attachStylesheet : function (href) {
        var $ = this.jQuery;
        return $('<link href="' + href + '" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />').appendTo('head');
    },

    makeSortable : function () {
        var iNettuts = this,
            $ = this.jQuery,
            settings = this.settings,
            $sortableItems = (function () {
                var notSortable = '';
                $(settings.widgetSelector,$(settings.columns)).each(function (i) {
                    if (!iNettuts.getWidgetSettings(this.id).movable) {
                        if(!this.id) {
                            this.id = 'widget-no-id-' + i;
                        }
                        notSortable += '#' + this.id + ',';
                    }
                });
                return $('> li:not(' + notSortable + ')', settings.columns);
            })();

        $sortableItems.find(settings.handleSelector).css({
            cursor: 'move'
        }).mousedown(function (e) {
            $sortableItems.css({width:''});
            $(this).parent().css({
                width: $(this).parent().width() + 'px'
            });
        }).mouseup(function () {
            if(!$(this).parent().hasClass('dragging')) {
                $(this).parent().css({width:''});
            } else {
                $(settings.columns).sortable('disable');
            }
        });

        $(settings.columns).sortable({
            items: $sortableItems,
            connectWith: $(settings.columns),
            handle: settings.handleSelector,
            placeholder: 'widget-placeholder',
            forcePlaceholderSize: true,
            revert: 300,
            delay: 100,
            opacity: 0.8,
            containment: 'document',
            start: function (e,ui) {
                $(ui.helper).addClass('dragging');
            },
            stop: function (e,ui) {
                $(ui.item).css({width:''}).removeClass('dragging');
                $(settings.columns).sortable('enable');
            }
        });
    }

};

iNettuts.init();
```

Comment: @Arun Code has been updated. Have you got any answer ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're following [this nettuts tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/inettuts/). Looking at the code, it strikes me that it's doing a lot of stuff you don't actually need for the requirements you have described.

The tutorial makes use of [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/home) and, of particular interest to you, the [draggable interaction](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/). I would encourage you to look at and try to understand the documentation for this. It will definitely allow you to achieve what you're trying to do, and an understanding of the mechanics, without a bunch of extraneous code to distract, will definitely help you in the long term.

Comment: I have tried some plugins, I was unable to achieve what I need. Because its been complicated.

Comment: Let me know how you get on and remember to accept the answer if it works out for you.

Comment: no this is not the way am looking for but i got my result using nettuts.